# is valid = false and and error = .... a local variable or global variable

Tags: global, local

```
def intcheck(question, low, high):
    valid = False
    error = "Please enter an integer bewteen {} and {}".format(low, high)
    while not valid:
            try:
                response = int(input(question))
                if low <= response <= high:
                    return response
                else:
                    print(error)
                    print()
            except ValueError:
                    print(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both valid and error are local variables because they are declared inside of a function. Global variables are declared outside any function. This concept is called scope. Local variables can only be utilized within the confines of the function they are declared in.